# $f(iz) = if(z)$ for $f$ a holomorphic function from the unit disk to some open square

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the unit disk, $Q = \lbrace a + bi \mid a, b \in (-r, r) \rbrace$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}$ be the open square and let $f : D \rightarrow Q$ be a conformal map with $f(0) = 0$. I want to show that

$$ f(iz) = if(z)$$
for all $z \in D$. In my attempt, I tried to consider the function $f(iz) - if(z)$, which must be either $0$ or a conformal mapping $D \rightarrow U$ for some $U$. It would then suffice to show that this cannot be a bijection for some reason, like $U$ not being conformally equivalent to $D$, but that does not seem to be the way to go, since it's hard to find out what $U$ actually looks like. It seems like using some part of the Riemann mapping theorem is required here, but I don't really see which part and how.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $g(z)=-if(iz)$ is *also* a conformal map $D\to Q$, Then $h:=g^{-1}\circ f$ is an automorphism of $D$. There are not many such automorphisms, and the way I defined $g$, you can readily show that $h$ is the identity

Comment: The automorphisms of $Q$ are exactly the rotations $1, i, -i, -1$, right? This leaves not that many options to check, at least. We have $g^{-1}(z) = i f^{-1}(-iz)$, thus $g^{-1}(f(z)) = i f^{-1}(-if(z))$, which is either equal to $iz, -iz, z, -z$. I don't really know how to determine which one it is without knowing the image of a point other than zero though

Comment: @tolUene: There are plenty of other automorphisms of $Q.$ Take any disk automorphism  (Mobius transformation) $\phi,$ then (assuming $f$ is invertible) $f\phi f^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $Q.$ In fact, all the automorphisms of $Q$ are of this form.

Comment: @Bumblebee Thanks. This means that the proof sketch given in the answer doesn't work?

Comment: @Hagen: This has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @tolUene: I think you misunderstood my comment. Both $Q$ and $D$ has many automorphisms, not just rotations. And we have a [complete description](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_18/unit%20disk%20maps.pdf) of automorphisms of $D.$